# concatenate 2-D arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation

In **MATLAB** in  a for loop I get a 2-D array created say `A`. Then what I want is I want to create another array,`B`, which concatenates all the arrays of `A` at each iteration and create a single array `B`.
So for example initially I have my array `B` to be empty. Then after 1 st iteration I get the array `A` say,

```
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9].
```

Then I want `B` to be `[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]`.
Then before the next iteration I set `A` to be zeros and from the for loop I get a new matrix `A`, say `[11 12 13;14 15 16]`.
Then what I want is to append this matrix `A` to `B` so that B would be
 `[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;11 12 13;14 15 16]`.
Here at each loop iteration the array `A` that gets created has the same no.of columns, say 3, but the no.of rows of `A` can be different.
So my `B` has 3 columns, but I don't know how many rows it would have beforehand.

How can I create this matrix `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertcat`

It would be something like :

```
B=[1,2,3;4,5,6];
A=[11,12,13];

B=vertcat(B,A);
```

Check the matlab help, you'll learn alot there.

Comment: You're declaring a cell array.  Use `[]` to define numeric matrices.

Comment: my bad, confusing different languages. @rayryeng thanx a bunch man

Comment: No problem at all.  +1 for your answer as this is correct.